java 8 end of support on App Engine flexible environment
I'm using Eclipse to deploy Java applications to the Google App Engine Flexible Environment. Now I must upgrade the code to Java version > 8. The following warning is prompted:
"Java 8 and earlier versions will reach end of support on 2024-07-10 for App Engine flexible environment."
I have now done all the updates and checks, but I can't select the Runtime environment for Java 11 in the project facets. (See picture below).
Projet Facets
I have update all the dependencies so far. The project has no errors

Which version of Eclipse are you using? And which version of that facet?
